# How to get entry by title by using wpdb

Tags: wpdb

I've create a form by metabox and save data in custom table

my table is:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'aacv';
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id int(20) Not Null,
    name varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    post_title varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    food_selected varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    guest_number bigint(20)  NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);";
```

I want to get entry WHERE LIKE post title by this code:

```
<?php $abcde = $abc = the_title();
                    $mylink = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_aacv WHERE post_title LIKE' .$abcde); ?>
                    <?php foreach ($mylink as $post){ ?>
                    <?php echo $post->food_selected;} ?>
```

but not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_aacv WHERE post_title LIKE '".$abcde."' ');
```

Comment: error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in

Comment: can u post full error..

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /home3/adalatne/public_html/nahar/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/content.php on line 74

Comment: It's error on content page & you are working on your custom page.. right??

Comment: Change the quote in query `"select * from wp_aacv where post_title like '".$abcde."' "`

Comment: no custom page ! Its content.php at 2014 themplate. And your last code return same error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /home3/adalatne/public_html/nahar/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/content.php on line 74

Comment: [Link]http://nahar.adalatnews.ir/

Comment: Error resolved but query not work and not to any thing display

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php $abc = the_title();
 $abcde = '%' . $abc . '%';


      $mylink = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_aacv WHERE post_title LIKE' .$abcde); ?>

             <?php foreach ($mylink as $post){ ?>

             <?php echo $post->food_selected;} ?>
```

Comment: Tanks a lot my friend